# Problem with the priority of services in a push-flow production

Tags: service, push

I am facing an issues with the **priorities of my service blocks** that effects the productivity of my simulation.

I have build an linear production systems with a push flow. So, the source creates a certain amount of parts per time unit and pushes it through the production system. The production system contains services, queues and selectOutputs. The priority of every service is getting bigger with ever service step. (Service 1 - Priority 5 / Service 2 - Priority 10 and so on.)

**Now my issue:**

Let's say, service 5 (out of 15 service blocks in total) is the most time consuming step. Therefore, it should always be executed in order to reduce the throughput time. It is a semi automated process. That means, that step 4 need an operator out of the operator pool to start the process. Service 5 itself is then executed automatically.

The following steps 6-15 are less time consuming. Due to the my logic of the flow production they do have a higher prioritization though. The problem with that is, that the service steps 6-15 get executed before step 4/5 although they aren't the critical/the bottleneck.

**What I basically want to achieve is, that step 4 gets executed by an operator whenever needed. When this has been done, the operator should continue with the required service step further in the production process (6-15). This ensures, that the critical step 5 always gets executed when possible.**

The problem is, that if i give step 4 the highest priority, the flow of agents just stops.

I haven't found any solution concerning that problem in the Any Logic help guide. 
I would be very thankful for any kind of help! Thanks.

Comment: sorry, maybe I didn't quite understand, but it sounds like using Seize/Release across steps 4-15 would solve it, no? Whenever you seize someone for step 4, that resource continues with the agent until step 15 is done... ?

Comment: I second what @Benjamin said :)